# Prove the product topology is the equivalence of metric topology in a special case.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Define a topology T on D$^\Bbb N$ with D={0,1} and the discrete metric as the following: C $\in$ T is basic iff there's an i $\in \Bbb N$ such that $C := C_1 \times C_2 \times...\times C_j \times D \times D \times...$, (a $\in$ C is of the form $a:= (a_1,a_2,...,a_j,x,y,...)$ where $a_i \in C_i$ and $1 \le i \le j$, there are $j$ numbers of nonempty open sets $O_j$ of D; if $i \ge j+1$, then $x,y...$ are arbitrary elements of X.

Show that T is the topology of the metric d:
$$d ((a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty, (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty ) := \sum_{ n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \frac{ d_n(a_n,b_n)} { 1+ d_n (a_n,b_n) } $$